# Dart: Calling a dynamic function variable with dynamic amount of arguments

Tags: function, dart, unit-testing

I am trying to create a list of functions with differing amount of arguments, and then doing something generic with them - namely setting up mocks and verifications that have the same behavior across all methods regardless of arguments.

The following code works, but need to have a case for every possible count of arguments. I am wondering if there is an elegant way of doing this which works for any number of arguments.

```dart
final funcs = {
  printer.getStatus: [],
  printer.setPrintAreaSizeParams: [printAreaSizeParams],
}

for (final func in funcs.entries) {
  if (func.value.isEmpty) {
    test('not connected ${func.key}', () {
      expect(
        () async => func.key(),
        throwsA(isA<InvalidConnectionStateException>()),
      );
    });
  } else if (func.value.length == 1) {
    test('not connected ${func.key}', () {
      expect(
        () async => func.key(func.value.first),
        throwsA(isA<InvalidConnectionStateException>()),
      );
    });
  } 
}
// ...
```

Comment: Look at how https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/hash.html does it, with a sentinel value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, [`Function.apply`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.3/dart-core/Function/apply.html), and it even accepts a `List` for the arguments:

```dart
final funcs = {
  printer.getStatus: [],
  printer.setPrintAreaSizeParams: [printAreaSizeParams],
};

for (final func in funcs.entries) {
  test('not connected ${func.key}', () {
    expect(() => Function.apply(func.key, func.value),
      throwsA(isA<InvalidConnectionStateException>()),
    );
  });
}
```

For the record (pun intended), you shouldn't use a map as a list of pairs.
Use a list of pairs as a list of pairs.

```dart
final funcs = [
  (printer.getStatus, []),
  (printer.setPrintAreaSizeParams, [printAreaSizeParams])
];
for (final (func, args) in funcs) {
    test('not connected $func', () {
    expect(() => Function.apply(func, args),
      throwsA(isA<InvalidConnectionStateException>()),
    );
  });
}
```